# I dont get AppendChild to work with PowerShell 2, but with version 3 it works fine

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this `XML`-file that I want to add a node "`Profile`" inside the node "`Profiles`".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration LastWrittenBy="Me">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <ActiveProfile>None</ActiveProfile>
  </Settings>
</Configuration>
```

The code below worked fine for me on my test client using `PowerShell 3`. But when I use it on other clients, where I am not able to update `PowerShell (v. 2)`, problem arise.

```
$xmlpath = "C:\Temp\profileSettings.xml"

Load xml-file to an object
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($xmlpath)

# Create a node
$xmlElt = $xml.Configuration.SelectNodes("Profiles")
$xmlSubElt = $xml.CreateElement("Profile")
$xmlElt.AppendChild($xmlSubElt)

#Save to file
$xml.Save($xmlpath)
```

I get this error message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XPathNodeList] doesn't contain a method named 'AppendChild'.
At C:\Temp\Test\test.ps1:10 char:20
+ $xmlElt.AppendChild <<<< ($xmlSubElt)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (AppendChild:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I did have another test client that was running `PowerShell 2`, which I updated to correct the problem. So I am pretty sure that the different version of `PowerShell` mess things up for me :) (but I might be wrong). I am not allowed to update software on the clients where I need to run a script with this functionality.

Any idea how to workaround this? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SelectNodes can return multiple nodes, you need to iterate the collection on V2 e.g. try:

```
$xmlElt | Foreach {$_.AppendChild($xmlSubElt)
```

Or if you are only expecting a single node use `SelectSingleNode()`.  This works on V3 because it will automatically enumerate collections when invoking a property or method.